# How to remove duplicate values between keys within a defaultdict(list)

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates, defaultdict

I have a `defaultdict(list)` where some keys have common values and I want to remove those that are common, so that no same values are found between any keys. So the duplicate value is only kept in once (**not** removed completely). Here is how it looks at the moment:

```
defaultdict1 = {100 : [(400, 500)], 110: [(400, 500),(440, 888)], 300: [(494,585),(272, 574),(2772, 4848)]}
```

The desired output would be:

```
new_defaultdict1 = {100 :[(400, 500)], 110: [(440, 888)], 300: [(494,585),(272, 574),(2772, 4848)]}
```

If there is a way to do this check while I am building the `defaultdict1`, that would be even better, but I don't know how. If it is easier to do this with a stepwise process, that's OK.

Also, I can't know for sure how it will end up in my code, but from which key the duplicate value goes out doesn't matter, so in this case only `100` had the `(400,500)` pair, it could be that `110` would keep them.

I figured a way like this but this doesn't quite do what I want: 
I create a list where I keep only the values of the dictionary that are not duplicate:

```
unique_list = []
for k, v in defaultdict1.iteritems():
     for member in v:
        if member in unique_list:
            pass
        else:
           unique_list.append(member)
print unique_list
```

the unique_list now looks like: 
    unique_list = [(400,500), (440, 888),(494,585),(272, 574),(2772, 4848)]

The problem is that I lost track of where those member came from. Any help please?

Comment: Why did I get a -1 marking?

Comment: Perhaps you can use class set instead of list. And dunno, seems like a fair question.  Unfortunately it's also a pretty common question that you didn't make much effort to research.  google "python list unique".

Comment: @KennyOstrom: Thank you for your reply. I sort of found it a bit tricky in this case as the lists are within a defaultdict(list) and as you see I am not dealing with one list, but with many lists which are in turn values to different keys. This is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it please anyone correct me if I am wrong, but I do get the right output: 
    import collections
    from collections import defaultdict

```
unique_list = []
unique_defaultdict = collections.defaultdict(list)

 data= {100 : [(400, 500)], 110: [(400, 500),(440, 888)], 300: [(494,585),(272, 574),(2772, 4848)]}

for k, v in data.iteritems():
    for member in v:
        if member in unique_list:
            unique_defaultdict[k].append('None')
        else:
            unique_list.append(member)
            unique_defaultdict[k].append(member)

print unique_defaultdict
```

This way I keep still have the keys and their values 'connected' to them still intact. So this prints:

```
 defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {100: [(400, 500)], 110: ['None',(440, 888)],300: [(494,585),(272, 574),(2772, 4848)]})
```

So where there used to be a duplicate value it is replaced by 'None'. Couldn't think of anything better.

Comment: There is one problem with my answer. It leaves out of the unique_defaultdict any keys which have their values knocked out because they were also values to some other key. I tried it with a bigger data dictionary and just found out. Any hints from someone? Thanks

Comment: Ah, this is indeed different.  If the points are the unique values, perhaps they should be the key?

Comment: This works with some minor syntax fixes, like unique_list=[].  Do you care which of the duplicate points is kept?

Comment: @KennyOstrom: What do you mean "the points"? What I mean, in this case is not obvious, but say if 110 only had (400,500) then 110 wouldn't appear as a key in the unique_defaultdict, and to me it's necessary to keep all keys but remove only the values that appear again in the data dictionary.

Comment: @KennyOstrom: Yes sorry that was a typo. in my code I have it as unique_list = []. Do you mean whether the duplicate will stay under the '100' or under the '110' instead? No I don't care, as long as it appears only one, and any keys that will eventually be left with no values, should still stay in the unique_default. I am also looking at the remove() and pop() functions of lists to see if that gives anything.

Comment: change the data to data= {100 : [(400, 500)], 110: [(400, 500),(440, 888)], 300: [(400,500),(440,888),(494,585),(272, 574),(2772, 4848)]}
 and I get an output dict which has only 300 as a key.  (The order the keys come up in dict.iteritems may be different in your implementation.  I do not know if python has any standardization with the hash algorithm used in dicts, or not)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83759/discussion-between-kenny-ostrom-and-hr123r).

Comment: @KennyOstrom : see the change I made with the 'None'.

Comment: That works.  You do get a lot of extra None entries, and have to check them every time you look at the data.  You could add this at the end of the loop: if not k in unique_defaultdict.keys(): unique_defaultdict[k] = []